# Are BLE indications acknowledged in android snoop log?

Tags: java, android, c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

A simple question.

Should we expect to see evidence of indications being acknowledged in the Android snoop log file?

I have an app derived from the esp-idf gatt_server example which is sending indications (not notifications) every 10 seconds to an adroid phone using BLE.

All I can see in the android snoop log is a record of a notification being sent from the esp32 board to the android phone.

Is this normal?

I can quite see that it could work without an ack. The sender OS could just pause for a millisecond or two and, if the connection is still intact, assume that the packet was received successfully.

Does anyone know what goes on under the hood?

It might be a problem with my programming. Perhaps, somehow, I've failed to enable indications (as opposed to notifications). The app at the android end queries the server

BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = TxChar.getDescriptor(CCCD);
int properties = TxChar.getProperties();

and the PROPERTY_INDICATE bit is set

also, at the Android end

gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(TxChar,true) succeeds so I'm reasonably confident that it's all OK.

At the ESP32 end the send_indicate function succeeds when the phone is in range and fails when the phone is out of range as you would expect.

You can download a dump of the snoop log from here.

https://netleysc.uk/snooplogdump.xlsx

Comment: To my understanding the Android Bluetooth system handles indication response already in the abluetooth stack so on Android app level you won't see any response. Not sure about the snoop log but as it is designed to help app development I would assume that it is also captured at the app interface level and thus doesn't get any information about indication responses.

Comment: On line 140 I see the confirmation for the indication of line 138. No other indications are sent according to your log file. Only notifications later on, which shall not be confirmed. So when you say that your device sends indications every 10 seconds, what happens instead is that your device sends notifications.

Comment: In the snoop log I can see an ATT packet sent from the esp32 board to the samsung phone at 15:45:18, 2023-06-09 15:45:28, 2023-06-09 15:45:38, etc.

Comment: Emil, thanks for the comment. Are you saying that, if, indeed, the esp-32 board was sending indications I would see the word 'indication' rather than 'notification' on the ATT line. I've never seen indications working - so I don't know what to expect.